# Cascade same layer through WMS and WFS

Tags: qgis, geoserver

I'm WMS cascading a layer from a QGIS server into GeoServer, so I can use symbols from QGIS. Is there some way to cascade the same layer both through WFS and WMS with the same name?
I want to use GeoServer's access right feature, so I need to cascade and not ask QGIS directly. When I publish the layer for WMS, the name of the layer is reserved and I need to change either the layer name or workspace for WFS.

Comment: tag QGIS for your question.

Answer (score 1):

Yes and No; You can't publish two layers with the same name GeoServer just won't allow that as it would be confusing. However, you can use the WFS as a datastore in GeoServer and then publish layers from that store via the WMS and WFS endpoints.